# accessing values in arrays without throwing errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am relatively new to React development. I had a quick question. If I had an object like this:

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
```

I know that I can access the value of John by saying person['firstName']. But what if we did not know that firstName would be there. How can we try to access it without throwing an error if it is there.

I know that we can use trys and excepts but I plan on having 20-30 of these objects so I do not think it would be wise to have that many trys and except structures. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Accessing a property that doesn't exist will not throw an error. Your question is unclear.

Comment: First option to check the value exist in condition basis like if(person['firstName']){} if there is a value it will return true or else false. Second if you assigning it to a variable, you can use ternary operator as var fname = person['firstName'] ? person['firstName'] : ''; Javascript will always return undefined for non existing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
const obj = {
  name: "foo",
  job: {
    name: "doo",
    company: "boo",
  }
}

obj.name //foo
obj?.name //foo
obj.notExists //undefined
obj.notExists.somethingElse //ERROR
obj?.notExists?.somethingElse //undefined
obj?.notExists?.somethingElse?.map() //will not execute map, or any other method, if property does not exists
```

To use it with `[]` notation is like that:

```
obj?.["name"]?.["anything"]
```

Ps. be aware that this is an ES6 feature (or greater, not sure), so is not safe to use without a 'compiler' (it's safe if you're using react)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not throw errors if you attempt to access a non-existent property of an object; it returns `undefined`, instead.

If I had your object `person` from your example, and I attempted to access `person.middleName` or `person.favoriteCheese`, they would both simply return `undefined`.

You can test this easily in your browser's developer console. Just type `const a = {}; a.favoriteCheese;`.

Now, if I tried to access *further* -- for example, `middleInitial = person.middleName.substr(0, 1)` or `middleInitial = person.middleName[0]` -- then an error would be thrown, because I'm attempting to perform operations on `undefined`.

If you absolutely need to make sure that a property has a value, you'll have to do something like:

`if (person.firstName) { ... }`

If you simply want a fallback, you can use `||` or `??`:

```
// will set firstName to 'No first name!' if person.firstName is ANY falsy value
// (null, undefined, an empty string, NaN, false, 0)

const firstName = person.firstName || 'No first name!';
```

```
// will set firstName to 'No first name!' ONLY if person.firstName is null or undefined

const firstName = person.firstName ?? 'No first name!';
```

If you want to traverse nested objects safely, you can use JavaScript's [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator (often called a safe-navigation operator in other languages):

```
// If person.dog is undefined, dogName will be set to undefined,
// and JavaScript will not attempt to access down to person.dog.name

const dogName = person.dog?.name;
```